# Conditional Formatting using Excel VBT code

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, vba

I need to change the color of a cell in B row if a value is entered in a corresponding cell  in A row. I did this using the  formula in conditional formatting

`=OR(COUNTA($H3:$AG3)>5,COUNTA($H3:$AG27)>5* COUNTA($N3:$N27)) applies to -=$N$3:$O$27`
How to do this in vbt code for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop to go through each row or column, while there are values.

You can use Font.Color to set an RGB value (e.g. 255, 0, 0 for red) for the font.

You can use Interior.Color to set an RGB value (e.g. 0, 0, 255 for blue) for the cell background.

Below is an example of using these to loop through rows, changing the colour of the text in column B to green if the value in column A is 1.

```
Do While Len(Range("A1").Offset(counter, 0).Value) > 0

    If Range("A1").Offset(counter, 0).Value = 1 Then
        Range("B1").Offset(counter, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If
    counter = counter + 1

Loop
```

Hopefully you can use this a basis for your needs. If you wanted to loop through columns rather than columns for example just change the way the Offset is used, so the counter variable is the second argument, e.g. Offset(0, counter)

Comment: this changes the value of the cell in B to green color, I need the entire cell to change the color

Comment: Edited answer to include Interior, this changes the background.

Comment: I changed as `If Range("A1").Offset(counter, 0).Value = TRUE Then
        Range("B1").Offset(counter, 0).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)`

Comment: Suppose I am entering a value in A10 (only in A10), the color should be filled till B10. How to do that

Comment: Not sure I understand you. If you want to start the formatting from A10 simply change the A1 and B1 ranges in your code to A10 and B10 respectively. If you want to change cell colours up until a certain value in column A it may be better to add to or amend the Do While criteria, so it always changes the cell colours until a certain condition is met, e.g. `Do While Len(Range("A1").Offset(counter, 0).Value) <> "something"`. You could remove the If statement then.